# Just another php image exists issue

Tags: php, image, exists

All of this stuff is for example (names aren't actual).

Everything is also located on localhost:8080 (USBWebserver 8.5)

Directory Structure:
(Files located on localhost:8080/[project_name])

```
/ajax
    /ajax_file.php
/img
    /250x250
        /[image_name].jpg
```

Code (From ajax_file.php):

```
$url = 'img/250x250/'.$image_name.'.jpg';
$url = file_exists($url);
```

This will return false.

I've tried an img_exists($url) function which used cUrl that did not work.

I've also tried:

```
$url = 'img/250x250/'.$image_name.'.jpg';
$image_check = getimagesize($url);

if (!is_array($image_check))
{
    $url = 'img/default_image.png';
}
```

but this returns a warning for getimagesize() saying no file or directory exists.

When I put `$url = 'img/250x250/'.$image_name.'.jpg'` into `<img src="$url" />` the image shows up...but if the image does not exist then it comes up with a broken image...

How come anything I try to do fails in some way?

I want a default image to show up when the image is broken :/

**EDIT**

```
$url = 'img/products/250x250/'.$image_name.'.jpg';
$url = var_dump(file_exists($url));
Returns bool(false)

$url = '../img/products/250x250/'.$image_name.'.jpg';
$url = var_dump(file_exists($url));
Returns bool(false)
```

Comment: Show us where you get $code from? Or $image_name as it seems to have changed somewhere...

Comment: The $image_name comes from $_POST

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears as if you need to branch out of the ajax folder before accessing img folder?

Try:

```
$url = '../img/250x250/'.$image_name.'.jpg';
```

@Alex Lunix

My guess is that he put the img tag inside of the actual php page, not the ajax script.

Comment: The $url is being sent back in a $response.

Comment: kk I am trying to picture this :P so your sending this request through ajax to check if the file exists and send back the correct url to the calling page?

Answer (score 0):

If you're in `/ajax/ajax_file.php` and you look for '`img/250x250/'.$image_name.'.jpg'` it will be looking for `/ajax/img/250x250/'.$image_name.'.jpg`. Instead you should be using

```
$url = '../img/250x250/'.$image_name.'.jpg';
```

Although I'm not sure why it shows up in image tags, my guess is you're getting lucky and your browser is fixing the url.